# VS 2019 - seeing many warnings AD0001 from Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I get this exact warning many time in the `Error List` pane in VS 2019 (v16.4.2).

How can i resolve the warnings ?

```
AD0001 Analyzer 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.FixAnalyzers.CSharpFixerWithFixAllAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: not yet. i am in contact with the Roslyn guys , i`ll update here when i have something

Comment: I found that some nuget packages pull in analyzers as dependencies, while your code may pull in the same analyzers in a different version. This mismatch is one probable reason for this error.

Comment: @empi - see the resolution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its resolved,

An old version of the package was pulled in by an indirect reference.

adding the package as a direct dependency forces the use of the new version - resolving the warning.

[link to the github issue i opened](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3198)